# Connect as client to Ipsec with OpenSuse Linux

Tags: linux, opensuse, vpn, ipsec

A former co-worker established a set of AWS instances. One of these is an IPSec VSetup a IPSec/L2TP VPN server.

I can SSH into this ec2 instance, and on this machine.  I do have a username and password setup in this linux instance.

Now I have an OpenSuse 13.2 Linux laptop. I have been told to connect via IPSec to a particular hostname (vpn-ipsec.myhostname.com)

I don't recall ever having done this on a linux machine to connect to an ipsec vpn server. I don't expect this would be hard. I went into Network Manager to create a new connection, and I see a lot of choices, but I didn't see ipsec in particular.

I don't need a UI tool in OpenSuse, if there is one there, that's great, or if I could use some command-line tools to make that connection, that would be good also.  I have installed strongswan and strongswan-ipsec modules to my linux laptop.

Please let me know if there is any other information you might need.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a VPN compatible with openvpn?

Comment: Honestly, I do not know.   I do have openvpn installed on my linux system also.

Comment: I made an answer in regard to the three most common types of VPNs.  But I am making a comment because I found that you made the exact same question on StackOverflow.  Please do not crosspost that way, crossposting is frowned upon here on SE.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of VPNs, some common ones are `openvpn` (RedHat), `vpnc` (Cisco) and `pptp` (Point To Point Tunnel), each of them has a different way to connect from a *nix machine.  Yet there is `NetworkManager`, which uses a plugin system to support several types of VPNs.

My knowledge on `NetworkManger` is on Arch Linux but OpenSUSE has [documentation on using NetworkManager](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_113/opensuse-startup/cha.nm.html#sec.nm.configure).  Unfortunately NetworkManager is interfaced by a lot of graphical tools, and the command line tool (`nmcli`) has no good support for configuring a VPN client.

You can use of the many graphical interfaces (one of the many flavours of `nm-applet`).  Or you can hack together the configuration file.

First of all you need to make sure you are using NetworkManger as network configuration tool this is somewhere in `YaST` I believe.

Next you need to install the VPN plugins for NetworkManager:

- `NetworkManager-openvpn`
- `NetworkManager-vpnc`
- `NetworkManager-pptp`

The you need to configure a connection, let's call is `myvpn`.  In `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/myvpn` add the following (you can make up the UUID, just keep the format):

```
[connection]
id=myvpn
uuid=799ce6af-b88c-4119-9319-8d9a029cb6ee
type=wifi
permissions=
secondaries=

[vpn]
Xauth password-flag=0
IPSec secret-flags=0

[vpn-secrets]
Xauth password=<password to the VPN>
IPSec secret=<group key for the VPN>
```

Note that you should keep that file under `root` and with `-rw-------` permissions, since the passwords are in clear text!

Finally you can do:

```
nmcli connection up id myvpn
```

---

Extra note: NetworkManager is often quirky with VPNs, and `nmcli` does not make it easy to change the configuration.  What I normally do is to use `nm-applet` to configure the VPN and then `nmcli` to actually start it.

References:

- [OpenSUSE: Using NetworkManager](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_113/opensuse-startup/cha.nm.html)